# How to fix first column and header in Jtable

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, jquery-jtable

I am trying to see the property in jTable where i can fix the first two coloumns.

Is there is any way to do that. I am using jTable in aps.net

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code to  define your problem/question

Comment: Can you show us what have you done at this point? Any code sample would be great. Please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)